# IE10 CSS Keyframes animation issue

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-10

I've create an SVG loading indicator. It works fine in Chrome et al but I can't seem to get it working in IE10 - here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/288mu88o/

```
@keyframes loading {
    0% {
        fill: red;
    }
    100% {
        fill: yellow;
    }
}

.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4, .c5, .c6, .c7, .c8, .c9, .c10, .c11, .c12, .c13, .c14, .c15 {
    animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
}

.c1 {
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
.c2 {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.c3 {
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

...

<g>
    <circle fill="#D9E2E7 " cx="294.7" cy="342.1" r="3.5" class="c1" />
</g>
<g>
    <circle fill="#D9E2E7 " cx="281.3" cy="344.8" r="3.5" class="c2"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle fill="#D9E2E7 " cx="270.2" cy="352.7" r="3.5" class="c3"/>
</g>

...
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: IE10 (or 11) does not support CSS animation of SVG data. You'd need IE Edge for this: https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/csstransitionsanimationsforsvgelements/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response it's much appreciated. I already have a meta tag defined in my index.html e.g. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">. Is this what you are referring to? If so, it makes no difference.

Comment: You can't upgrade IE10 to IE edge by putting in a meta tag. You need to install IE edge itself. Developers can implement backwards compatibility but, lacking a time machine forwards compatibility is somewhat harder.

Comment: To clarify, IE=edge instructs IE to use the highest available engine for established and emerging industry standards. Microsoft Edge is de deafult browser for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 does not supprt CSS animation of SVG. You could use a third party solution like [Fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/)

Comment: Fakesmile is for SMIL, not CSS animations.